# Lenovo Thinkpad X270 issue with NVMe disk

Tags: linux, windows, boot, uefi, openbsd

I bought a Lenovo Thinkpad X270 2 month ago and I needed to use Windows and OpenBSD on 2 differents hard drive. Fortunately, this Thinkpad had a free PCI-e port available [NVMe compatible](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad%20X270/ThinkPad_X270_Platform_Specifications.pdf) (M.2 2242 format), I bought a [Transcend TS256GMTS400](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-642).

- [Samsung NVMe SSD](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/ssd/client-ssd/MZNLN256HAJQ/) with Windows 10
- [Transcend SATA SSD](https://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-642) with OpenBSD-current (FDE + UEFI support)

After 3 weeks without any kind of issue, the Transcend seemed defectuous and after a simple [smartctl test](https://www.smartmontools.org/), my system (running OpenBSD at this time) crashed. The Transcend hard disk was not usable anymore and my OpenBSD data was gone.

I decided to try another brand, I bought this time a [Toshiba RC100 240G](https://ssd.toshiba-memory.com/en-amer/ssd/rc100). I installed OpenBSD on it for a first time, but, this new disk did not appear when I press the F12 key at startup for choosing the boot device. Strange thing, because the transcend was present on the boot list. So, I decided to try to reinstall OpenBSD a second time: same issue. I tried to install Linux Mint and... I still can't see the disk on the boot device list!

After that I:

- installed OpenBSD (1) with [Full Disk Encryption](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq14.html#softraidFDE) (FDE) with [UEFI support](https://blog.jasper.la/openbsd-uefi-bootloader-howto.html)
- installed OpenBSD (2) without FDE with UEFI support
- installed OpenBSD (3) without UEFI support (classical installation)
- installed Linux Mint (classical installation)
- updated the [BIOS firmware](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/dk/fr/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x270/downloads/ds120442)
- updated the Toshiba firmware to the last version
- plugged/unplugged the Toshiba SSD (2 times)
- installed the [Toshiba SSD Utility tool](https://ssd.toshiba-memory.com/download/software/ssd-utility/3.1.3276/SSDUtility_3.1.3276_Windows.zip): all is good
- after installed Linux on the toshiba hard drive, the default boot loader is not windows anymore, but grub, I don't know why
- reset the BIOS with default configuration
- sent a hater tweet and waiting for some computer gods (should I sacrify something?!)
- after another reboot, I can now see a "ubuntu" in the boot list. To be honest, I don't know what I did... We'll see if another OpenBSD installation will change something.
- used [installboot(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/installboot) manually on the toshiba hard drive

For your information, if I plug an USB drive, I can see it on the boot device list, I can also the other NVMe disk (samsung), my first transcend disk was also present on this list.

The disk is present during the BIOS diagnostic at startup, but I cannot choose it when I want to select my bootable device. I tried different configuration on the BIOS with UEFI, Legacy method and nothing work.

Do you have an idea why? Maybe I missed something during the configuration or NVMe devices are not seen like a disk by the bios?

## Installing bootstrap on first NVMe disk

I don't find a clean solution, and does't solve my first issue: where is my NVMe hard drive in the boot list, but it gives the opportunity to switch from windows to OpenBSD on the UEFI boot list.

On Windows, I used diskpart tool to mount the EFI partition and remove `ubuntu` directory, moved also `Boot` directory to `Boot.old`. I did not touch the Windows directory.

```
C:\> DISKPART
DISKPART> sel disk 0
DISKPART> sel volume 2
DISKPART> assign letter Z:
```

On OpenBSD, or whatever unix system, I created a `Boot` directory in EFI partition and copied the file `bootx64.efi` in it. I can now boot on the Toshiba hard drive with the Samsung one. I did the same with an USB flash drive, and work.

```
# mount /dev/sd2i /mnt
# cd /mnt/EFI
# mv Boot Boot.old
# rm -rf ubuntu
# mkdir Boot
# cp /usr/mdec/BOOTX64.EFI Boot
```

At boot, you should see the OpenBSD bootprompt, you must set manually your booting device, `sr` drive for NVMe. Here the code sample:

```
boot> set device sr0a
boot> boot
```

## Only one NVMe disk can boot

If you have 2 NVMe disks on your Thinkpad X270, it seems you can only [boot on one of them](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X270-SATA-or-PCIe-NVMe/td-p/3641309), here the solution given by incidentflux on the Lenovo Forum:

> A dual drive SSD config is possible as follows:
>
> ### Option 1 - 500MBps/Value - SATA (AHCI)
>
> With SATA (AHCI) cable:
>   1. Drive 1 in 2.5 inch bay: 2.5 inch SSD with SATA connector cable
>   2. Drive 2 in WWAN slot: m.2 2242 SSD (look up B or M keying)
>
> FRUs Required: 01HW968, CRU ID:2, FRU HDD Cable for SATA HDD/SSD,
>   01HY565 CRU ID:N FRU M.2 Adapter&HDD Bracket ASM
>
> ### Option 2 - Fastest/Pricey - m.2 (PCIe) Or with an M.2 (PCIe) cable:
>
> 1. Drive 1 in 2.5 inch bay: m.2 NVMe (m.2 cradle inside a 2.5" caddy)
> 2. Drive 2 in WWAN slot: m.2 2242 SSD (look up it's B or M keying)
>
> FRUs Required:  01HW969, CRU ID:2, - FRU HDD Cable for PCIe SSD,
>   01HY565 CRU ID:N FRU M.2 Adapter&HDD Bracket ASM
>
> When ordering, the SATA or m.2 NVMe option, the cable  Lenovo
>   provides, for m.2 nvme SSD is key to your future expansion.
>
> SATA cable is provided with SATA Webstore option and m.2 cable is
>   provided with m.2 Webstore option.
>
> I think that's why its not in self service (See pages 55, 56, 77, 78
>   of HMM). Major FRU Part numbers 8a, 8b, 9a, 9b, 10a, 10b.

Does not answer my question, but give you some hints of you need to buy a Lenovo Thinkpad X270 and add another drive. Anyway, if you are like me and don't really understand what is B or M keying, you can find more information about that on [Republic of Gamers website](https://rog.asus.com/articles/maximus-motherboards/buying-an-m-2-ssd-how-to-tell-which-is-which/). The big picture: it is the numbers of pins (socket) on the PCI-e connector of your NVMe SSD.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would check the X270 Hardware Maintenance Manual. It seems that it is possible to have 2 NVMe, a person has described his solution on Lenovo Forums site [here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X270-SATA-or-PCIe-NVMe/td-p/3641309).

Comment: You're right, my first Transcend SSD was not NVMe but was using SATA interface. I don't have another M.2 2242 format to test that. I will correct my question, thanks.

Comment: Only a partial answer. their no solution actually to boot with 2 NVMe disk, so their no solution actually. But I will add a summary of the link.

Comment: Thank you for exploring the case, and adding the summary, Mathieu! I would have done it, but my laptop is not X270, so I restrained myself from giving advises that could proof useless afterwards.

Comment: It seems the WWAN port does NOT support nvme. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I can confirm that an "M" key 2242 NVMe SSD will not fit into the WWAN port on the X270. I tried, and was disappointed. I can use a M+B keyed M.2 SATA SSD in there however.